# How can I learn which devices/OS versions my iOS app is being run on?

Tags: iphone, ios, analytics

I understand that apple no longer allows me to send "device data" to third-party services. As a result of this, Flurry and presumably every other analytics company no longer collects OS/hardware version data. However, this data is very valuable to anyone trying to target development toward the people who are actually using the apps.

I can imagine a few different ways to collect this data.

1) Send a custom event indicating the hardware/os version to Flurry. This, of course, is in direct violation of the agreement with Apple. However, I suspect plenty of people are doing this, and just not getting busted. Still, not an ideal solution. Even if Apple didn't notice that we were sending this data, I'd rather not have the possibility of the app getting pulled hanging over my head.

2) Use an analytics package which allows me to collect data on my own server. Localytics is one company which seems to offer this. However, I don't think they offer this with their free plan. Is anyone aware of any free (or cheap) analytics tools which will allow me to send data to my own server?

3) Roll my own solution. This could either be an entire replacement for Flurry, or I could continue to use flurry, but send only the device data to my own server. This is a little clunky. I'd much rather have all my analytics data in one place. And would much rather not have to deal with building my own tool if I don't have to

So, is anyone else collecting device data? Are you using one of the above techniques? Or maybe something different I hadn't thought of?

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it, I don't see how Flurry could mine my device data if I'm using custom events to log info about OS and hardware version.

Comment: That's a good point - you could just send the info as events to your own Flurry account.  There terms and conditions do allow them to mine it though (as long as they remove reference to your specific app and only provide the "domain" of the app).  Whether they would do it or not I don't know.  There's also nothing stopping you from calling iPhone4 "Fluffy Bunny" and 3.1 "Purple Monkey Dishwasher" - which would likely be a needless obfuscation.

Comment: Agreed. Even without the hilarious obfuscation, I can't imagine it would be worth flurry's time to look at every account, examine the custom events, try to figure out if actual device data is being sent, and coerce that data in to a common format across all accounts. That said, it sure would be annoying to have apple pull my app because of a violation of the letter, if not the spirit, of the agreement.

Answer (score 1):

Hi maybe "Testflight Live" could help you.

As far as I know Testflight is allowed by Apple.

https://testflightapp.com/sdk/live/

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of people using UIWebViews to connect to a webpage with a counter.  The counter is incremented each time a page is accessed, and the pages are separated by feature/UIView.  This way the developer can tell which features get the most usage.

As far as device data, you most likely are looking at rolling your own tracking mechanism, probably going through a server like Google App Engine that's set up to receive your data.

I made this an answer so I could continue to check back, because I'd like to know some more info as well.  I voted up your question and favorited it

Good luck, sir

Comment: I suppose I could build a web site which has separate pages for each hardware version, and each OS, and hit them accordingly, and then track them using google analytics or something. That would be a little crazy and convoluted, and technically _would_ be sending device data to a third party, though not in a format they'd every be able to use.