# How to find percentage of users on different iOS devices (not OS versions)?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

How to find percentage of users on different iOS devices (not OS versions) ? Is there a source from where I can get this information. It would help developer to decide whether go through pains of supporting older devices and sometimes even iPads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the iPhone you can look it up at Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:IPhone_sales_per_quarter_simple.svg
And for the iPod Touch it will be likely the same. But in general your App should run fine on at least the 2nd Gen Devices.

Comment: Thanks that was the closest data I can find.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for your own app, you can at least get iPhone / iTouch / iPad from Google Analytics. If you're using Flurry or something else, this article suggests some ways to send the data yourself, though technically Apple doesn't approve it.

[How can I learn which devices/OS versions my iOS app is being run on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081942/how-can-i-learn-which-devices-os-versions-my-ios-app-is-being-run-on)